# How to get userstories from a Project - Pyral

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyral

I am trying to fetch all the UserStories of a specific Project (say project 'Bolt' in workspace 'ABC').

After the connections are set (using username, password and server) and my workspace is set to a default workspace.

I navigate to a different workspace like below -

`rally.setWorkspace('ABC')`

`rally.setProject('Bolt')`

Now to get the UserStories, I write the code as below -

`response = rally.get('HierarchicalRequirement', fetch=True)`

I see I get a lot more number of UserStories, than we have in that Project.

I try this -

`response = rally.get('HierarchicalRequirement', fetch=True, project="Bolt")`

Again I see the count is high. Like I have 50 UserStories in Rally for that Project, but here I get 90 UserStories.

Please suggest how can I get the UserStories from a Project.

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following approach:

```
from pyral import Rally

SERVER = 'SERVER'
USER = 'USER'
PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD'
WORKSPACE = 'WORKSPACE'
PROJECT = 'PROJECT'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rally = Rally(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, workspace=WORKSPACE)

    project_req = rally.get('Project', fetch=True, query='Name = "%s"' % (PROJECT))
    project = project_req.next()

    user_stories = rally.get('HierarchicalRequirement', fetch=True, query='Project = %s' % (project.ref))

    for user_story in user_stories:
        #do all required stuff
        pass
```